# Padding in empty <td> not working properly in IE7

Tags: html-table, internet-explorer-7, padding

I have a simple page with products-list (downside) and basket (upside). When i click on any product in products-list, it will move `img` from product's list `td` to basket's `td`. It is realized by tables with some width, height and paddings of td's. But in IE7 there is an issue with `padding-top` when `td` is empty. Please, look at this image and tell me, why `td` in products-list (the grey ones) are not affected from `padding-top`?

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In IE, if a `td` tag is empty, it consider it does not exists. Add a `&nbsp;` (HTML entity for space) in each `td` who have no content to avoid this bug.

Comment: So why padding-left is working? I cannot put &nbsp; in td, it will disrupt it's structure. But thanks anyway)

Comment: There are some things in IE even God can't understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you might be able to use `border-top` rather than `padding-top` to fix this issue.